# Ошибка при data['main']['temp'] Openweather

Tags: python, json, telegram-bot, telebot, openweathermap

```
import time #Імпортуємо бібліотеку тайм, щоб потім зробити затримку
import sqlite3
import requests
import json
import telebot
from telebot import types
# Replace 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN' with your actual bot token
bot = telebot.TeleBot('6k')
name = None

API='5d'
@bot.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
def wetn(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Зараз я тобі допоможу з погодою. Стоп а яку місто? ️')
@bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
def get_weather(message):
    city = message.text.strip().lower()
    res = requests.get(f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid={API}&units=metric')
    data = json.loads(res.text)


    temp = data['main']['temp']
    wind = data['wind']['speed']
    cl = data['clouds']['all']
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Саша Стефанюк\Desktop\My\MyfirstBot\main.py", line 188, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)#Робимо код нескінченним
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Саша Стефанюк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1043, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "C:\Users\Саша Стефанюк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1118, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Саша Стефанюк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1074, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\Саша Стефанюк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 147, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\Саша Стефанюк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 90, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Саша Стефанюк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 6801, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Саша Стефанюк\Desktop\My\MyfirstBot\main.py", line 22, in get_weather
    temp = data['main']['temp']
           ~~~~^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'main'
```

Comment: Что должен делать ваш код?

Comment: и в чем заключается вопрос? непонятен смысл ошибки чи что?

Comment: НИКОГДА не публикуй свои токены и прочие ключи в интернете!

Comment: Спасибо! Я хотел чтоб мой бот мог писать погоду. Не могу запустить етот код. Как пофиксить ето

Comment: Во-первых проще должно работать: `data = res.json()`, во-вторых просто сделайте `print(data)`, да посмотрите, что у вас там за структура, есть ли там ключ `main` в словаре, или что там вообще есть.

Comment: {"coord":{"lon":-0.1257,"lat":51.5085},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":7.49,"feels_like":3.81,"temp_min":6.59,"temp_max":8.71,"pressure":1019,"humidity":57},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":6.69,"deg":340},"clouds":{"all":14},"dt":1700833870,"sys":{"type":2,"id":2075535,"country":"GB","sunrise":1700811175,"sunset":1700841696},"timezone":0,"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}

Comment: Есть и если я ето перенису у другой бот оно будет работать

Comment: Хм, странно. А это вы прямо `print(data)` сделали перед той строчкой, где `temp = ` вычисляется? Может не каждый раз правильный `json` приходит?